# Android Current Running App not shown in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, package-managers

I am trying to show installed apps in listview, but I don't want to show current app, meanz my app name is **APP1** so i don't want to show this app in listview, how can i remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a BaseAdapter just check the app1 from the applist inside getView() @Override method and skip that element before setting the value to the TextView.